# SQL Referential Integrity Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

`CREATE TRIGGER FK_INTEGRITY_CHECK
BEFORE INSERT ON sch_book_list
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN ((SELECT resource_cd FROM sch_resource WHERE resource_cd = NEW.resource_cd) IS NULL)
        THEN RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table "sch_book_list" violates foreign key '|| 'constraint "FK9qti8knho9i047jd1lrwqwy2x"')
    END
END;`

> This is my trigger code but there is some syntax error. I don't know what the error is?

Comment: Whats is the functon `RAISE()`? MySQL does not have it.. Also MySQL does not support `||` string concat unless enabled so i very doubt your are using MySQL here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CASE`, you can store the count in a variable and check the value, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER FK_INTEGRITY_CHECK
BEFORE INSERT ON sch_book_list
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DECLARE row_count INT;
    SET row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sch_resource WHERE resource_cd = NEW.resource_cd)
    IF (row_count = 0) THEN
      RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table "sch_book_list" violates foreign key '|| 'constraint "FK9qti8knho9i047jd1lrwqwy2x"');
    END IF;
END;
```